# Get all Keys/Array keys in JSON parse Object?

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I have sample JSON like this

```
`{
  values:[{
    "name": "Base Url",
    "url": "https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Base Url newwww",
    "url": "https://batman.com"
  }]
}`
```

Currently when I add this paticular JSON to the lodash `_.keys` gives me the result `["0", "1"]` which is basically the index of first and second object `0` and `1`.

What I exactly want is to retrieve all the keys of the JSON object including sub object properties as well. In this case `["values","0", "1","name","url"]`

Does anyone knows a lodash method or a mechanism to retrieve all the keys given in complex JSON object to nth level?

language : Angular + Typescript

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you have isn't a "JSON object," it's an array.

Comment: Please check now edited more meaningful manner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get keys (path to) the deepest nested object in a javascript nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378137/how-to-get-keys-path-to-the-deepest-nested-object-in-a-javascript-nested-objec)

Comment: Makes no difference (and still isn't JSON). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function recursively gets the keys from an objects tree, using `_.keys()` and `_.flatMap()` and `_.union()` to combine lists of keys, and get only the unique values:

```js
const getAllKeys = obj => _.union(
  _.keys(obj),
  _.flatMap(obj, o => _.isObject(o) ? getAllKeys(o) : [])
)

const arr = {"values": [{"name":"Base Url","url":"https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"},{"name":"Base Url newwww","url":"https://batman.com"}]}

const result = getAllKeys(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea without lodash, using `Object.values()` and `Array.flatMap()` to iterate the current object (or array), and `Array.concat()` and a Set to make the keys unique:

```js
const getAllKeys = obj => [...new Set([].concat(
  Object.keys(obj),
  Object.values(obj).flatMap(o => typeof o === 'object' ? getAllKeys(o) : [])
))]

const arr = {"values": [{"name":"Base Url","url":"https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"},{"name":"Base Url newwww","url":"https://batman.com"}]}

const result = getAllKeys(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Without array indexes:

```js
const getAllKeys = obj => _.union(
  _.isArray(obj) ? [] : _.keys(obj),
  _.flatMap(obj, o => _.isObject(o) ? getAllKeys(o) : [])
)

const arr = {"values": [{"name":"Base Url","url":"https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"},{"name":"Base Url newwww","url":"https://batman.com"}]}

const result = getAllKeys(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like the edit fixes the issue I raised, nice!

Comment: Would this solution works for any dynamic JSON object with complex structure? Ex: can have arrays inside even.?

Comment: Both solutions handle dynamic structures of objects and arrays.

Comment: Sorry for the fustration it works fine.. I have put semicolan accidently... Thanks for the answer.. Marked as correct answer.

Comment: Hi is it possible in the above solution to avoid getting array indexes?

Comment: Sure. Added another answer without the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need lodash for this, `Object.keys` is sufficient. You just write a recursive function, writing to a `Set`, perhaps converting to array when you're done:

```js
const array = [
  {
    "name": "Base Url",
    "url": "https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Base Url newwww",
    "url": "https://batman.com"
  }
];

function addAll(set, entries) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
        set.add(entry);
    }
    return set;
}

function allKeys(obj/*: object|array*/, keys/*: Set<string>*/ = new Set()) {
    addAll(keys, Object.keys(obj));
    for (const entry of Object.values(obj)) {
        if (entry && typeof entry === "object") {
            allKeys(entry, keys);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

console.log([...allKeys(array)]);
```

Or using the structure in your edit:

```js
const array = {
  values:[{
    "name": "Base Url",
    "url": "https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Base Url newwww",
    "url": "https://batman.com"
  }]
}

function addAll(set, entries) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
        set.add(entry);
    }
    return set;
}

function allKeys(obj/*: object|array*/, keys/*: Set<string>*/ = new Set()) {
    addAll(keys, Object.keys(obj));
    for (const entry of Object.values(obj)) {
        if (entry && typeof entry === "object") {
            allKeys(entry, keys);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

console.log([...allKeys(array)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```js
const arr = {"values": [{"name":"Base Url","url":"https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"},{"name":"Base Url newwww","url":"https://batman.com"}]}

let result1 = Object.keys(arr) // get the object keys which is "values"
let result2 = Object.keys(arr[result1]); // get the keys of the object name "0,1" here
let result3 = Object.keys(arr[result1][0]); // get property names of one object "name and url" here
let resutltant = result1.concat(result2, result3) // "merge array"
console.log(resutltant)
```

Assuming that your object properties names will remain constant

Answer (score -1):

If you use typescript why don't use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries) or Object.values to do that?

You need to add to tsconfig the next line:

lib: [
......
"es2018",
]